# MSTest project can't get localized string?

Tags: string, localization, project, mstest, resources

I ran into a strange problem. In my unit test, I want to check the localized strings. However, I can't seem to get it work. For example, I created two resources: Resource1.resx for English and Resource1.zh-CN.resx for Chinese. The unit test project can only get the (default?) English resource string. This is the code I'm using:

```
ResourceManager actual = new ResourceManager(typeof(LocaleTest.Properties.Resource1));
string name0 = actual.GetString("Name", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
string name1 = actual.GetString("Name", new CultureInfo("zh-CN"));
```

I created another regular project (means not a MSTest project) to make sure the localized strings are working. So, it works in a regular project, but not in a MSTest project.

It didn't help even if I put the following code to make 'zh-CN' as the current culture of the unit test:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("zh-CN");
}
```

Anybody has seen similar problems? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't you need to use [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute(VS.80).aspx) to ensure that the localisation DLL is in the test folder?

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem(@"bin\Debug\fr\Proj.resources.dll", "fr-CA")]
public void TestDialogLocalization(){
 // blah
}
```

Comment: Oh, Great. That is the cure! Thank you a million!

It's interesting though...the resources.dll has already been copied to test project's directory respectively. Adding this attribute doesn't re-copy the file (from the timestamp). However, without this attribute, it doesn't work.

Comment: Nice catch. I like to put this at the top of my test methods with `[DeploymentItem]` to sanity check my file copying: `Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(@"nl\Project.resources.dll"), "File not found");`

Comment: It worked for me but i had to write: `[DeploymentItem(@"fr\Proj.resources.dll", "fr-CA")]`