# Localization test is failing from the command line, but working successfully in VS

Tags: unit-testing, localization, mstest

I have the following method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Message_TestToEnglishString()
    {
        // Set the thread to French to get the French resource
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr");
        string frenchMessageBase = MessagesResources.USER_LOGGED_IN;

        Assert.AreNotEqual("{0} logged in.", frenchMessageBase);

    }
```

This works exactly as intended in Visual Studio. The same test run on the same code from the commandline fails as the value is pulled from the English resources file which is `"{0} logged in."`.

Any insight as to why this is happening, and how to fix it?

This particular test will pass if I set the resources file Culture, i.e. `MessagesResources.Culture` however there are additional tests later on that call the resources file directly.

Comment: Maybe a path problem, similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686815/mstest-project-cant-get-localized-string ?

Answer (score 1):

try setting also Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Answer (score 1):

Are the resources accessible from the command line version of the application in the same way as they are accessible from Visual Studio?

[image]